# Overload in function on a class type

Tags: c++, header-files

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
#include "lineType.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double x, y;
    double a = 1.; 
    double b = 0.; 
    double c = 1.; 
    double d = 2.; 
    double e = 0.; 
    double f = 3.; 
    double g = 0.; 
    double h = 4.; 
    double i = -1.;

    lineType line1(a, b, c);
    lineType line2(d, e, f);
    lineType line3(g, h, i);

    cout << "Line 1: ";
    line1.display();

    if (line1.isParallel(line2)) cout << "line1 is parallel to line 2" << endl;
    if (line1.isPerp(line3)) cout << "line 1 is perpendicular to line 3" << endl;

    if (line2.intersect(line3, x, y))
        cout << "The intersection of lines 2 and 3 is at point(" << x << ", " << y << ")" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Lines 2 and 3 do not intersect." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This is the code I am testing and the issue I am getting is c2661 no overloaded function takes 3 arguments
    My Header file is:
    #pragma once

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class lineType
{
private:
    double a;
    double b;
    double c;
public:
    void display() const;
    bool isParallel(const lineType& line) const;
    bool isPerp(const lineType& line) const;
    bool intersect(const lineType& line, double& x, double& y);
    lineType();
    lineType(double a2, double b2, double c2);
    ~lineType();
};
```

This is the lineType.cpp file that was wanted

```
#include "lineType.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

void lineType::display() const
{
    cout << a << "x + " << b << "y = " << c << endl;
}

bool lineType::isParallel(const lineType& line) const
{
    if (a == 0 && line.a == 0)
        return 1;
    if (b == 0 && line.b == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (-a / b == -line.a / line.b)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

bool lineType::isPerp(const lineType& line) const
{
    if (a == 0 && line.b == 0)
        return 1;
    if (b == 0 && line.a == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (-a / b == line.b / line.a)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}

bool lineType::intersect(const lineType& line, double& x, double& y)
{
    if (a == 0)
        x = c / b;
    if (line.a == 0)
        x = line.c / line.b;
    if (b == 0)
        y = c / a;
    if (line.b == 0)
    {
        y = line.c / line.a;
    }
    else
    {
        x = ((a*line.c) - (c*line.a)) / ((b*line.a) - (a*line.b));
        y = ((c*line.b) - (b*line.c)) / ((b*line.a) - (a*line.b));
    }
    if (a == 0 && line.a == 0)
        return 0;
    if (b == 0 && line.b == 0)
        return 0;
    return 1;
}

lineType::lineType()
{
    a = 0;
    b = 0;
    c = 0;
}

lineType::lineType(double a2, double b2, double c2)
{
    a = a2;
    b = b2;
    c = c2;
}


lineType::~lineType()
{
}
```

The error message that appears
Error (active)  E0289   no instance of constructor "lineType::lineType" matches the argument list   Project1    line 20
Same error message for lines 21 and 22 in the source.cpp file. so I am not sure what is occuring?

Comment: You don't appear to have a`lineType` constructor that takes 3 parameters.  You only have this one: `lineType();`

Comment: I did just make a constructor that does take the three parameters but it still is not accepting it. This is what I added into the code in the header file lineType(double a2, double b2, double c2);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lineType::lineType`, which is the constructor, is implicitely generated, since you did not provide any user defined constructors. Default-generated constructors take no arguments, yet you try to provide three arguments in lines:

```
lineType line1(a, b, c);
lineType line2(d, e, f);
lineType line3(g, h, i);
```

I suspect you wanted to take advantage of [aggregate initialisation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), which you can't unfortunately use, since your `a`, `b` and `c` variables are `private`. You might want to add such constructor yourself:

```
lineType(const double a, const double b, const double c)
        :a(a), b(b), c(c) { }
```

But that's not all. You have couple more problems with your code. Notably:

```
if (line1.isParallel(line2)) cout << "line1 is parallel to line 2" << endl;
```

contains a typo. It should be `isParrallel`, as declared in your class (which is also a typo) instead of `isParallel`. Fix either of these.

Lastly, the line:

```
if (line2.intersect(line3, x, y))
```

will not compile, since `intersect()` returns `void`, not `bool`. `if` statements require that they are provided either `bool`s or something that's implicitely convertible to `bool` type. Make your function return `bool`, which is the logical assumption for a function that's name starts with `is`.

Comment: I did fix the issues you suggested except the lineType constructor I added a lineType(double a2, double b2, double c2); along with it equaling the private information in the class, but it still runs into the same error

Comment: Then post your **full** error message and point out to where it refers. You might also want to share your `.cpp` file

Comment: I just posted the lineType.cpp file and error message. I am very thankful for your help as it has helped fix a great portion and am sorry If I am missing anything else.

Comment: @DerekLanger I copy pasted your code to my IDE and it compiles and runs fine. Cannot reproduce the error. Are you sure that you included everything?

Comment: @DerekLanger consider compiling and running the code on different IDE / different compiler and see if you can reproduce the error there. Maybe it's an error with Project Structure or a bug in your IDE / your compiler

Comment: THANK YOU, I finally got the code running but I had to basically create a new program than copy and pasted as It was not working for some reason in that file and I have no idea why but thank you once again.

Comment: @DerekLanger then please consider accepting this answer by clicking the tick below the score, so the future visitors will know that this indeed fixed the issue